Html interaction (select and click-submit) with Selenium under C#
I am trying to interact with an html page with Selenium and I cannot perform the actions that I would like to.
I have a form to fill-in with two sets of actions that needs a final validation before the page gets refreshed with the relevant elements.

Select some months (one or multiple). By default, at least one month (the first one) is always selected, so no empty selection can go through. Every selected month goes into a container under its corresponding <li> element. A selected element can be removed from the container by checking the "x" <span> sign under the <li> element. The container also has a "search" feature that allows scrolling through the list of month items that shows as the last <li> element. In the excerpt below, "May 2024" and "Jun 2024" is the container after these two elements were selected.

Alternatively, one can select all months by clicking on the "Select All" checkbox. It has the effect of filling the container with all selected items.

Finally, press the button "Submit" to validate the choice. The page displays the message "Updating..." until it is fully re-displayed.
     <div class="select-2-div col-auto pl-0" data-select2-id="115">
         <div data-select2-id="114">

             <select multiple="" id="maturityDates" class="select2-search__field select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="maturityDates" tabindex="-1">
                 <option selected="true" value="04-2024" data-select2-id="2">Apr 2024</option>
                 <option value="05-2024" data-select2-id="4">May 2024</option>
                 <option value="06-2024" data-select2-id="5">Jun 2024</option>
                 <option value="09-2024" data-select2-id="6">Sep 2024</option>
                 <option value="12-2024" data-select2-id="7">Dec 2024</option>
                 <option value="03-2025" data-select2-id="8">Mar 2025</option>
                 <option value="06-2025" data-select2-id="9">Jun 2025</option>
                 <option value="09-2025" data-select2-id="10">Sep 2025</option>
                 <option value="12-2025" data-select2-id="11">Dec 2025</option>
             </select>

             <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="219">
                 <span class="selection">
                     <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
                         <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
                             <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="May 2024" data-select2-id="27">
                                 <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
                                 May 2024
                             </li>
                             <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Jun 2024" data-select2-id="28">
                                 <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
                                 Jun 2024
                             </li>
                             <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
                                 <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list">
                             </li>
                         </ul>
                     </span>
                 <span class="dropdown-wrapper"></span>
             </span>

         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-4 mb-0">
         <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="select_all_dates">
             <label class="custom-control-label" for="select_all_dates">Select all</label>
     </div>

     <div class="mr-2">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="submit_options_form" value="submit">Submit</button>
         <div class="form-der-refresh">
             <span class="text-sm">Updating...</span>
         </div>
     </div>

 </div>



Selecting one or multiple elements will allow visualising an information table for each of the selected elements. The one or multiple tables deploy after the selection area within a card-header and card-body frame. These cards display the information about each month that I want to read. Without going into the details of their content, the various card-headers re-display the selected month items.
<div class="card-header">
    <div class="w-100 d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row align-items-lg-center justify-content-between">
        <h3>May 2024</h3>
    </div>
</div>

So, checking on these headers <h3> allows checking whether the interactions have been properly completed.
Unfortunately, nothing seems to happen and I always end up with one unique card display that corresponds to the first default item, in the instance, "Apr 2024". I have tried many things but with no success.
My routine goes as follows:
// Create a Chrome driver service.
string browserPath = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";                  
string driverPath = @"C:\Program Files\Google\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe";                   
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverPath);
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;                                                         

// Set driver launch options.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = browserPath;
options.AddArgument("--headless");                                                              
options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");                                                    
images.options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.managed_default_content_settings.images", 2);             
sheets.options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.managed_default_content_settings.stylesheets", 2);    

using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options))
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(myAddress);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
    
    string myLocator1 = "//select[@id='maturityDates']";
    string myLocator2 = "//button[@id='submit_options_form']";

    // 1) Select.
    wait.Until(d =>
    {
        IWebElement element = d.FindElement(By.XPath(myLocator1));
        if (element.Displayed && element.Enabled)
        {
            SelectElement select = new SelectElement(element);
            select.SelectByValue("05-2024");
            select.SelectByText("May 2024");
            IWebElement option = select.SelectedOption;
            string value = option.GetAttribute("value");
            string text = option.GetAttribute("textContent");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
    
    // 2) Click.
    wait.Until(d =>
    {
        IWebElement element = d.FindElement(By.XPath(myLocator2));
        if (element.Displayed && element.Enabled)
        {
            try
            {
                // Execute Selenium action to click on the submit button.
                Actions actions = new Actions(d);
                actions.MoveToElement(element).Click().Build().Perform();
                element.Submit();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                try
                {
                    // Execute Java script to click on the submit button.
                    IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)d;
                    string id = element.GetAttribute("id");
                    string type = element.GetAttribute("type");
                    string value = element.GetAttribute("value");
                    executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
                    executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
                    executor.ExecuteScript(id, element);
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}

After the first block is executed, "1) Select", the string value and text are still locked on "04-2024" and "Apr 2024" respectively. During its execution, I get from time to time a no such element exception:
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@id='submit_options_form']"} (Session info: chrome-headless-shell=123.0.6312.123); [...]'

During the second block execution, "2) Click", the Selenium action often (but not always) throws some changing exceptions:
1) OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable (Session info: chrome-headless-shell=123.0.6312.123)'

2) OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element would receive the click: [...]'

whilst the Javascript fallback does not do much.
